# Can Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins be applied via data attributes at a time of my choosing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

*Using Bootstrap 2.3.2*

I'm using RequireJS and Backbone to load a bunch of markup dynamically from templates. I believe that because this happens after the Bootstrap module is loaded, the data attributes in the markup are not evaluated by Bootstrap so its JavaScript plugins are not applied.

One option is to use the JavaScript API, but I would really prefer to use the markup data attributes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm having a similar issue where the data-spy='affix' is not working on my site at all.  I believe it's because by the time bootstrap's js file is loaded the "window.load" event has already passed.

Given this situation, I don't believe you would be able to add data- type flags after the window is loaded without retriggering the load event.

The following code snippet is from their source for the Affix javascript plugin.  Like me, you will probably have to use the javascript way of setting these things up.

```
// AFFIX DATA-API
// ==============

$(window).on('load', function () {
  $('[data-spy="affix"]').each(function () {
    .. initialization stuff here ...
```

Comment: What happens if you run: `$(window).trigger('load')`?

Comment: That's what I would probably have to do, but I decided to just use the javascript portions.  What I'm wondering is how people normally use Bootstrap JS components with RequireJS, it seems no matter when I add the library it's after the load event has occurred.